# What is for (;;) used for?

Tags: c, for-loop

For example,

```
for (;;)
{
//do something
}
```

How is this different from

```
{
//do something
}
```

Comment: An idiom for `while (true forever thing) { // do something until break... }`

Comment: If you tried them both you'd probably see the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's an infinite loop.  Pretty much the same as writing

```
while (true) 
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is used as an [**infinite loop**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_loop). It is equivalent to `while(1) { ... }`.

Answer (score 0):

It is equivalent to while(true).

A for-loop has three elements:

initializer
condition (or termination expression)
increment expression

Since this doesn't set any of them, it continues to run.

Answer (score 0):

In C,

```
for (;;){
    //do something
}
```

is the equivalent of

```
while(1){
//do something
}
```

(Similarly, in other languages:)

```
while(true){
//do something
}
```

Comment: In Java, `while(1)` doesn't type-check. Similarly for pretty much any strongly typed language. Do you mean `while(true)`?

Comment: @JanDvorak you're right - edited my answer. I meant for that snippet to be about C, since C doesn't have booleans by default without including stdbool.h.

Comment: I thought most header files included bools by default? Is it `null` I am confusing it with?

Comment: @JanDvorak I think it's null. If you write a basic C program with only stdio.h and stdlib.h included, you get: error: ‘bool’ undeclared (first use in this function)